# Do I need to call Synchronize from TTimer events?

Tags: delphi, synchronization, ttimer

When I access global variables or the VCL from a `TTimer`, do I need to use `Synchronize`? I use the same variables and objects from a `TThread`, where I already use synchronization.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question. I would recommend rephrasing to make it clearer.

Comment: Already answered, but to be a bit more clear, a `TTimer` is not a `TThread` in any way. A Timer is a cheap way of performing something repeatedly within its calling thread (in this case the main thread) whereas `Synchronize` is something which is very specific to a `TThread`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TTimer's OnTimer event is executed under the main thread. You don't have to synchronize access to VCL inside that event

Comment: Well, to be clearer, the `TTimer.OnTimer` event fires in the context of the thread that creates the `TTimer` instance, as `TTimer` creates an `HWND` internally and thus has thread affinity. If that happens to be the main thread, then the `OnTimer` event will run in the main thread, yes. But if the `TTimer` is created outside of the main thread, then you would have to synchronize.